# Unity 5: Como fazer o jogo voltar exatamente onde tinha sido encerrado na sua última execução?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity3d

Exemplo: o cara estava jogando e no meio da fase ele fechou o jogo, daí como fazer para que quando ele abra o jogo novamente ele volte exatamente na parte (ou fase) que ele tinha sido encerrado?

Comment: Vc chegou a fazer algum tutorial relacionado à serialização de dados na Unity, [como esse](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-save-and-load-your-players-progress-in-unity--cms-20934), por exemplo? Creio que salvar *exatamente* o estado do jogo vai ser complicado, mas você pode salvar alguns dados relacionados ao avatar do jogador e/ou à fase em que ele se encontra, e então carregar a partir dali.

Comment: Realmente seria difícil, mas se salvar apenas a fase, moedas e itens mesmo que volte a fase no início já está bom! Vou dar uma olhada aqui, Obrigado.

Comment: Achei um pouco amplo essa pegunta, seria interessante você saber onde você quer chegar, qual o resultado final esperado. Pois você pode salvar estas informações de diversas formas. Manipulando diversos tipos de arquivo, PlayerPrefs, não destruir o objeto entre loads e por ai vai. Encontre uma abordagem que faça sentido em cada parte do teu jogo, e se encontrar problemas poste uma pergunta mais direcionada. Só estas três que citei dão um vídeo de uma hora cada uma sem entrar em detalhes. Imagina escrever tudo aqui numa resposta.

Comment: Ok, eu estava procurando sobre isso, é o único item que falta para mim começar um game (pois antes reuni todos scripts que irei utilizar e testei (alguns faltam ajustes)). O jogo tem além das fases, um inventário, e os coletáveis (moedas), daí é isso que eu teria de salvar, não importando o meio de fazer isso.. A pergunta foi assim porque pensei que seria mais simples "pausar" o game ao fechar e continuar quando abri-lo.